# Error in Selenium/Python script while a cycle that contains 'webdriver wait until' on Instagram

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I'm coding a script that set likes on instagram photos, but after some likes (once 14, once 50, once 64), the shell gives me this error:

```
in <module> ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dCJp8.afkep.coreSpriteHeartOpen._0mzm-"))).click() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) TimeoutException: Message:
```

I understand that the problem should be in webdriver wait,but I don't know how to improve my script.

this is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher")

#log in 
time.sleep(1)
usm = driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys("givcomomvrvglino")
pwd = driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys("x")
btnLog = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('form').submit()

#disattiva le notifiche
ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".aOOlW.HoLwm"))).click()

tag = "likeforfollow"

url_to_search = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + tag + "/"

driver.get(url_to_search)

contatore = 0

for i in range(500):
  if i == 0:
        ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w"))).click()
        ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dCJp8.afkep.coreSpriteHeartOpen._0mzm-"))).click()
        ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow"))).click()

  else:
        ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dCJp8.afkep.coreSpriteHeartOpen._0mzm-"))).click()
        ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow"))).click()

  contatore = contatore + 1

  print(contatore)

  time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Did you try increasing the wait time? The specified value is in seconds, and the condition (by default) is polled every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: I'm new to Selenium, and I don't know how to do this

Comment: In `ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 20)`, the "20" is the wait time in seconds.

Comment: I tried but it's the same

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned *shell gives this error sometimes after some likes (once 14, once 50, once 64)* so virtually there seems to be no definite/specific error as such.

If you look at the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of *Instagram*:

- The *css* contains reference to **react-root**

  ```
  <style type="text/css" data-isostyle-id="786433">#react-root,article,div,footer,header,main,nav,section{-webkit-box-align:stretch;-webkit-align-items:stretch;-ms-flex-align:stretch;align-items:stretch;border:0 solid #000;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;-webkit-flex-shrink:0;-ms-flex-negative:0;flex-shrink:0;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative}</style>
  ```
- The `<body>` starts with a `<span>` tag with contains the **react-root** as follows:

  ```
  <span id="react-root">
  ```

So as your [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) are based on those dynamic classes e.g. `v1Nh3`, `kIKUG`, `_bz0w`, `_0mzm-` etc, the search for the elements are bound to fail anytime either too early or a bit later during your *Test Execution*.

---

### Solution

A propersolution would be to use *Locating Strategies* based on *satic elements* present within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

As an example to `click()` on the element with text as **Not now** on *Instagram popup notification* you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Not Now')]"))).click()
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [Click ''Not now" on Instagram notifications ask using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563095/click-not-now-on-instagram-notifications-ask-using-selenium-and-python/53564742#53564742)